# How do I list a specific user's permissions on a teamdrive using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Per the [Google API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list) it looks like a Drive.Permissions.List call would work on a Teamdrive, however I am getting a 404 error when using the following:

```
Drive.Permissions.list(TEAMDRIVEID);
```

Is there an alternative way to get a specific user's permissions to a specific drive?

Comment: Have you enable the Drive advanced service and enabled the Google Drive API on Google API Console (Cloud Platform)?